# How do you call an assembly function from C program?

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am very new to Microcontroller programming particularly [PIC18F87J11](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en027149), and I am using MPLAB C18 compiler. I was reading the datasheet for various topics such as saving to memory or working with timers. I noticed the examples are written in assembly language, but I have minimum experience with it. Is there a way to use the power of Assembly and C together in my project?

I do not understand assembly that good or else I would try to convert the code to C, in this case, I rather just use the assembly code with few changes.

Now can someone show me an example of how you would use an assembly function in a C program with MPLAB C18 compiler?

The assembly function can be as simple as hello world. I just need to understand the process of combing and using two different languages on MPLAB. I tried to create a quick function for testing, but I did not know where to put the assembly code. Do assembly codes need their own files included in the project?

I hope someone can enlighten me with a full simple example just to be able to see the big picture. I appropriate the help in advance, thanks!

Comment: there is no such things as `__asm` in c but if you have asm compiler you can create asm lib and use it then like here descripted: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/232120-calling-assembly-routines-from-c/

Comment: Are you sure that's not possible? I was reading this [book page 229](http://books.google.com/books?id=CB9GaAU1dwsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and it looks like you can do it. I tried to implement the example, but I could not do it yet. I am still looking for a simple hello world example. Thanks!

Comment: @Heather - there may be no such thing as `__asm` in the C standard, but most current actual C compilers do implement something of that sort, though the syntax will vary.  The question does not reference the C standard, but rather a particular named compiler.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I didn't knew that. Can gcc do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without access to the compiler I can't test this, but the *MPLAB C18 C Compiler User's Guide and Release Notes* which I found [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014) states:

> #### 2.8.2 Inline Assembly
>
> MPLAB C18 provides an internal assembler using a syntax similar to the MPASM
>   assembler. The block of assembly code must begin with `_asm` and end with `_endasm`.
>   The syntax within the block is:
>
> `[label:] [<instruction> [arg1[, arg2[, arg3]]]]`
>
> `...`

So, it would seem to me that one solution might be to embed something like this in your .C file

```
void myAsmFunction()
{
  _asm
  // The asm code you've been looking at
  _endasm
}
```

Then call myAsmFunction from wherever appropriate. If you're wanting to include parameters and return values then it gets a little trickier.

Comment: Relative [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865676/how-to-use-inline-assembly-with-mplab-c18) you might be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

There's a way to use asm in C language, depending on the compiler you use (the capacity to use asm in C is not part of the standard). Each compiler doesn't use the same syntax. With MPLAB C18 it's something like this:

```
void main()
{
     _asm
                movlw 0x57
                movwf PORTB
    _endasm
}
```

The example above is from this [link](http://it441.groups.et.byu.net/class_notes/c_and_asm_for_pic.htm), which will explain you how to use asm in C with MPLAB C18.

Comment: Relative [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865676/how-to-use-inline-assembly-with-mplab-c18) you might be able to help.