# How to use Inline Assembly with MPLAB C18?

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am using MPLAB C18 which provides an internal assembler to enable calling assembly functions from a C project. I am following the rules on how to use Inline Assembly and I suspect something about '**Full text mnemonics must be used for table reads/writes**' is causing a syntax error message upon building my project.

```
The internal assembler differs from the MPASM assembler as follows: 

No directive support

Comments must be C or C++ notation
Full text mnemonics must be used for table reads/writes. i.e.,
TBLRD
TBLRDPOSTDEC
TBLRDPOSTINC
TBLRDPREINC
TBLWT
TBLWTPOSTDEC
TBLWTPOSTINC
TBLWTPREINC
No defaults for instruction operands - all operands must be fully specified
Default radix is decimal
Literals are specified using C radix notation, not MPASM assembler notation. For example, a hex number should be specified as 0x1234, not H'1234'.
Label must include colon
Indexed addressing syntax (i.e., []) is not supported - must specify literal and access bit (e.g., specify as CLRF 2,0, not CLRF [2])
```

This is the code I am using which I got from the [PIC18F87J11](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en027149) datasheet about reading from flash memory.

```
MOVLW CODE_ADDR_UPPER ; Load TBLPTR with the base
MOVWF TBLPTRU ; address of the word
MOVLW CODE_ADDR_HIGH
MOVWF TBLPTRH
MOVLW CODE_ADDR_LOW
MOVWF TBLPTRL 
READ_WORD
TBLRD*+ ; read into TABLAT and increment
MOVF TABLAT, W ; get data
MOVWF WORD_EVEN
TBLRD*+ ; read into TABLAT and increment
MOVF TABLAT, W ; get data
MOVWF WORD_ODD
```

This is the modification I made in order to get the assembly code working. I suspect something about the **TBLRD*+**  is causing a syntax error.

```
 _asm

MOVLW CODE_ADDR_UPPER 
MOVWF TBLPTRU 
MOVLW CODE_ADDR_HIGH
MOVWF TBLPTRH
MOVLW CODE_ADDR_LOW
MOVWF TBLPTRL 
READ_WORD:
TBLRD*+ 
MOVF TABLAT, W 
MOVWF WORD_EVEN
TBLRD*+ 
MOVF TABLAT, W 
MOVWF WORD_ODD

_endasm
```

I hope somebody can clarify what '**Full text mnemonics must be used for table reads/writes**' means and what might be causing the build error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to double check, but I believe that you have to replace `TBLRD*+` with the mnemonic `TBLRDPOSTINC`.  I'll post an edit later to confirm.

Comment: It looks like `TBLRDPOSTINC` made it work, but I ended up with other errors. Please check my update.

Comment: @Ammar, you started this post with one question - which I have answered - and now you are asking me to troubleshoot the rest of your code.  The least you could do is provide an up-vote and check this as the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry dude, I just thought you probably have a clue about those build error as well. Would you like me to start new thread for the rest of problems and mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: @Ammar - That would be nice.  You have two completely different questions going on now in this thread.  One of which is to simply troubleshoot your code - which you need to do a little bit of :-).  One thing you may want to try is to not use the variables and put in the literal value. e.g. - `MOVLW 0x00`, etc...

Comment: You might be able to help me with [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179070/how-to-write-to-flash-memory-using-inline-assembly)