# How to use sysenter with 6th argument

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

i try to call mmap and it require 6 arguemnt as an input, with int 0x80 you can do it very easily like this:

```
  mov eax, 90
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, 512
  mov edx, 3
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, fd
  mov ebp, 0
  int 0x80
```

But with sysenter, the right way to call mmap, according to [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/how-to-use-sysenter-under-linux) is:

```
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0

  push return_addr
  push ecx
  push edx
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  sysenter
```

The problem is easy with 5 arguments or less, but how can I pass the 6th argument with sysenter when I have to save ebp like that?

Is it impossible to pass a 6th argument with sysenter?

Comment: IIRC, it's highly discouraged and not officially supported to manually use `sysenter` yourself; the ABI isn't guaranteed stable.  Instead, call via the VDSO wrapper.  If you want to know how to pass a 6th argument, single-step into the VDSO wrapper for an `mmap` system call made from C or something.  (Or if it falls back to `int 0x80`, then it's probably impossible)

Comment: Fortunately the 64-bit `syscall` ABI is stable and easily supports 6 args, and also doesn't need help from user-space to be able to return properly.  So only obsolete 32-bit code is a problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes sr addition question: why in this question example he only need 5 argument: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883547/mmap2-function-write-in-asm-call-in-c#30247610. And when i do the 6 argument with ebp equal 0 the eax return 0xfffff2 but if i remove it and follow the question example with 5 argument it work?

Comment: `mmap2` takes 6 arguments; the kernel will read all 6 from their arg-passing positions (registers or wherever else, I don't remember where sysenter expects the 6th).  If the value that happened to already be in one of the registers or memory happened to keep the kernel happy then it works.  Use `strace ./myprog` to see what args are actually getting passed.