# 16PIC877A Reset with C code

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am using PIC16F877a and I need program reset without using button. When I looked at datasheet and referance designs, there is a button on MLCR pin. If button was pushed, MCU was reset. But I need reset that can control with C code, I don't want to use reset button. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: By setting the WDT (Watchdog Timer) without disabling periodically (not calling the `CLRWDT` instruction), your PIC will reset after a short delay.

Comment: By calling a recursive function that will cause an internal stack overflow. It has depth of 8 so this will be rapid.

Comment: by outputting a signal to the reset pin, probably with a muxer or something like that to choose between hardware and software input, you can also trigger a reset in software.

Answer (score 2):

The format for MPLABX XC16 (assuming that this is the compiler you are using) is:

```
__asm__ volatile ("reset");
```

Depending on your processor, you can also examine the contents of the `RCON` register on startup to find out the cause of the reset (MCLR, software, watchdog timer, brownout, etc.)

Comment: It would probably be the XC8 since the 16F877 is an 8 bit controller

Comment: That is true. Compiler is XC8.

Answer (score 1):

PIC 8-bit MCUS have a software reset assembly instruction:

```
RESET
```

[image: reset instruction]

http://microchip.wikidot.com/8bit:rst

You will have to use inline assembly. I've never used inline assembly for a PIC, but from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850368/how-do-you-call-an-assembly-function-from-c-program) it looks like this is the correct syntax for MPLAB:

```
void soft_reset(void)
{
    _asm
        reset
    _endasm
}
```

Do note that, as the linked page states, an external watchdog timer is generally a better way to trigger a full system reset. With a soft reset, external devices are not also reset. With an external WDT, you simply stop petting the watchdog, and then it resets the whole board.

Comment: Code is not worked. "Asm" is unkonwn identifier. I dont know how wdt setup. I'll try.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I was assuming GCC.

Comment: Updated my answer for MPLAB.

Comment: WDT is control whole process i think. I need only 1 time reset. I mean you have a program, program is done first line to end line, pic will be reset. Taht is it. WDT is complicate for this. Am i right?

Comment: MCU's don't typically run to "the end" they run forever, usually with a `for (;;)` loop. If that's the whole reason you want to reset, then just put your whole program in an infinite loop.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: There's a GCC for PIC16 devices? (not counting xc8, which is a semi-proprietary & bastardized version of GCC). Genuine question, if there is such a thing as of recently, I'd like to know about it!

Comment: @ahmd14: You could simply enable WDT for said 1-time reset, and then let it expire to force a reset (just remember to also disable it the moment the microcontroller resets --- because I suspect WDT state might be preserved).

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: PIC16F series do not have the `reset` assembly instruction, the 18F series does. Either the Watchdog timeout solution can be used or one could connect a output pin to MCLR, and MCLR to VCC with a pull-up resistor. Setting the output pin low will hardware reset.

Comment: @Jonathan Reinhart: I have a main part (int main()) after that i am using "while(1)" loop. But first settings is changing(pushing buttons, changing variables etc.) and i have to return this settings to first step. There is global variables, and variables in main fuction. How can I return this variables to begenning state? Because of that i am searching a reset condition.

Comment: Also i can try power on reset but, that is not worked or i cant handle it. If power on reset can be usefull, i am happy to hear the solution about power on reset.

Comment: @Tim You are probably right in that there is no GCC for PIC - I was thinking of gcc-avr.

Comment: @user1320881 I looked for the documentation clarify which families had `reset` but only found the one stating that 8-bit ones did. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ahmd14 It still sounds like this is a software problem that you're trying to solve with hardware. A full reset should be the last resort, IMO.

Comment: @Tim Čas The XC16 compiler is GCC-based (`xc16-gcc.exe`), as is the XC32 compiler, I believe.

Comment: @EBlake: Yes, but XC16 is for PIC18, and XC32 is for PIC32, no? We're talking 8-bit PIC16.

Answer (score 1):

For XC8, use #asm and #endasm.  Using the example from the XC8 manual

```
#asm
RESET
#endasm

// do it again the other way...
asm("RESET");
```

Answer (score 0):

A microcontroller needs to be [reset](https://piestforum.com/questions/what-is-the-need-of-reset-in-microcontroller/) to get to a known state before program execution. Reset is typically generated by hardware signal from external sources, for example, you might find a reset button on the development board. Most microcontroller devices have an input pin for reset.