# Resetting PIC24FJ128GA010 with C

Tags: c, reset, pic

I have to implement a reset with MCLR when I push a button on PIC24FJ128GA010 controller.
Does anyone no if I have to connect a port to MCLR and write a zero or is there any default instruction on C to do it?

Comment: Related: [16PIC877A Reset with C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395154/16pic877a-reset-with-c-code). But if you are "pushing a button" why not pull down  MCLR directly?

Comment: This device has a software RESET. Means you can reset it in code. I don't know what IDE you use, but you can use ASM("RESET") instruction in your C code as per your compiler supports.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reset the controller with writing a zero to the MCLR port, but the controller has a build in reset function. Just use:

```
asm("RESET");
```

See here [for details.](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m576410.aspx)